# What comes first, a class level or bonus from leveling? (Prestige Class Question)

Tags: pathfinder-1e, prestige-class, character-levels

Example:

> Duelist
>
> Requirements: To qualify to become a duelist, a character must fulfill
>   all the following criteria.
>
> Base Attack Bonus: +6.  Skills: Acrobatics 2 ranks, Perform 2 ranks. 
>   Feats: Dodge, Mobility, Weapon Finesse.

Base Attack and Skill points are "things" that you must have a class to get (even racial Hit Dice count as a "class")!
Feats on the other hand, can be a reward for leveling, you gain one feat at 1st, 3rd, 5th and on and on....
So, to get +6 base and 2 ranks on a skill you must had those from previous levels... but feats...

Let's say that Bob is a level 6 fighter, he has base +6, acrobatics & perform rank 2, dodge & mobility, but he still didn't get weapon finesse.
at level 7 he gets a feat from leveling...

So, can Bob choose weapon finesse and right at the spot get Duelist, becoming Fighter 6/Duelist 1 or does he have to wait another level?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The PRD entry on [Classes](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/classes.html) spells it out pretty clearly:

> When adding new levels of an existing class or adding levels of a new class (see Multiclassing, below), make sure to take the following steps in order. **First, select your new class level. You must be able to qualify for this level before any of the following adjustments are made.** Second, apply any ability score increases due to gaining a level. Third, integrate all of the level's class abilities and then roll for additional hit points. **Finally, add new skills and feats.**

(emphasis mine)

So, Rules-As-Written, Bob would have to take Weapon Finesse after choosing to take a 7th level in Fighter (or a first level in ... whatever else) and would have to wait until 8th level to become a Duelist.

That said, this GM has always let players choose the order in which to perform the "adding a level" steps every time they level (which would allow Bob to become a Duelist at 7th level *or* become a 7th level fighter and choose a feat with a +7 BAB prerequisite, but not do both). I have never encountered any power/balance problems with this approach, but it's not RAW and YMMV.